# How to fix yield usage in this BST implementation?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, yield, recurrence

I would like to get values from tree as generator to iterate over them. In this case `yield` just gives me a single value. Function `print_tree` works as expected - it shows values from smallest to biggest. How to get similar result, but with catching them one by one? This is my BST implementation:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, element):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = element

    def add_element(self, element):
        if self.data > element:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(element)
            else:
                self.left.add_element(element)
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(element)
            else:
                self.right.add_element(element)

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.left: self.left.print_tree()
        print(self.data, end=' ')
        if self.right: self.right.print_tree()

    def get_values(self):
        if self.left: self.left.get_values()
        yield self.data
        if self.right: self.right.get_values()

    def get_structure(self):
        return (self.left.get_structure() if self.left else None, self.data, self.right.get_structure() if self.right else None)
```

Code for testing:

```
from node import *

x = Node(3)
x.add_element(5)
x.add_element(1)
x.add_element(7)

print(x.get_structure())        #result: ((None, 1, None), 3, (None, 5, (None, 7, None)))
x.print_tree()                  #result: 1 3 5 7
z = x.get_values()
print(list(z))                  #result: [3]
```

Could you please explain me where am I making a mistake and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you yield all elements from the left subtree, then the node value and finally all elements from the right subtree

```
def get_values(self):
    if self.left:
        yield from self.left.get_values()
    yield self.data
    if self.right: 
        yield from self.right.get_values()
```